# Multipolygon supposed to be contained by another but returned False with Shapely

Tags: python, shapely, multi-polygon, predicates

There are two multi-polygons `a` and `A` where `a` is supposed to be contained inside `A`. Using shapely, the following `difference` operator

```
b = a.difference(A)
print(b)
```

gives

```
POLYGON EMPTY
```

However testing `A.contains(a)` returns `False`; `a.touches(A)` also gives `False`.

How could this be possible with Shapely?

The wkt descriptions for `A` and `a` are hosted in the following Gist link (due to characters limit)
https://gist.github.com/vodp/169b12f507a9730c0dd2ac86ca2589db

### Edits

So what I am trying to test is assessing the equivalence between

```
a.difference(A) -> False
```

and

```
A.contains(a) -> True
```

But `A.contains(a)` returns `False` instead. If I were buffering a bit, for example

```
A.contains(a.buffer(-1))
```

then I get `True`. Notice that both

```
aa = a.buffer(-1)
aa.difference(A) -> EMPTY
```

and

```
a.difference(A) -> EMPTY
```

Does that mean for `contains` to work, none of the point of `a` lying in the boundary of `A` ?

Any chance this is because of rounding errors? I try to get the minimal buffering value and the smallest one I could get before `.contains()` return `False` is that:

```
A.contains(a.buffer(-0.000000001)) # 1e-9
```

Comment: did you check your geometries are both valid?

Comment: Both are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency between `a.difference(A) = POLYGON EMPTY` and `A.contains(a) = FALSE` is due to numerical precision issues.  The polygon a contains many vertices which are probably intended to lie exactly on the line segments of A.  But due to the limitations of finite precision floating-point, a point almost never lies exactly on a line segment.

As visible in the image below, some of these vertices lie outside the polygon `A`.

[image: Vertices not lying exactly on line segments]

The `contains` predicate computation (in GEOS) is evaluated with high precision, and so detects that there are vertices of `a` which lie outside `A`.  The reason that `difference` is not affected is that it contains logic to improve robustness which ends up snapping these vertices to the line.

It's hoped that a future version of JTS/GEOS will provide spatial predicates that can use a tolerance value to handle situations like this.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, `a.touches(A)` returns `False` because documentation says:

> `touches` returns `True` if the objects have at least one point in common and
> **their interiors do not intersect** with any part of the other.

[image]

Also `A.contains(a)` returns `False` because a lot of points of `a` lie in the extrior of `A`. Documentation says:

> `contains` returns True **if no points of other lie in the exterior** of the object and at least one point of the interior of other lies in the interior of object.

`a.difference(A)` returns empty geometry because all interior of `a` is in `A`. But `A.difference(a)` gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong when testing with `touches` indeed. What I do not understand is, if `a.difference(A) returns empty geometry because all interior of a is in A` then why `A.contains(a)` returns `False`?
 `object.contains(other): Returns True if no points of other lie in the exterior of the object and at least one point of the interior of other lies in the interior of object.`

Answer (score 5):

The solution is `a.symmetric_difference(A)`

Reread [The Shapely User Manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

> object.symmetric_difference(other)
> Returns a representation of the points in this object not in the other geometric object, and the points in the other not in this geometric object.

and not

> object.difference(other)
> Returns a representation of the points making up this geometric object that do not make up the other object.

nor object.contains(other) or object.touches(other) as Kadir Şahbaz says

A:

[image]

a:

[image]

a.symmetric_difference(A):

[image]

Comment: Then is it true if I say a is a subset of A thus `A.contains(a)` should return `True` ?

Comment: No, you must understand the binary predicates of shapely, because `A.intersects(a)` is true and therefore A cannot contains a

Comment: By Set theory, `intersects` is `True` if `contains` is `True`. They are not exclusive aren't they? That is true for Shapely too.

Comment: No because intersects returns True if the boundary(exterior)  or interior of the object intersect in any way with those of the other and contains returns True if no points of other lie in the exterior of the object.

Comment: My argument is not contradicting yours. What I mean is: if `A.contains(a) -> True` then `A.intersects(a) -> True` as well; the inverse is not always true.

And if `A.difference(a) -> EMPTY` and `A != EMPTY` and `a != EMPTY` then `a` must be contained inside `A` which means `A.contains(a)` must return `True`.